# Should radio applications mobile and browser auto play their streams?

Tags: stream, audio-streaming

Should applications developed for dedicated browser and mobile audio streams auto play their content when the application is first opened?

It came up as a request to disable the auto play and that there may be legal implications of playing the audio without the users consent.

What are the best practices with regards to auto playing dedicated audio streams from custom built applications, and does this also carry over to browser based implementations?

Answer (score -1):

I'm no lawyer... can't speak to any legal implications.  I can't imagine there would be any, but who knows.

The answer to your question is to do what the user expects.  If they simply opened your app, you might give them an opportunity to actually click play.  However, if your app opened as the result of a link that said "play now" or "tune in", then by all means, go ahead and start playing.

This is no different between apps or browsers, as far as user expectation in this regard.

Also, you should know that Chrome is about to start blocking autoplay:  https://blog.chromium.org/2017/09/unified-autoplay.html  Others will likely follow.

You might consider re-posting this to http://ux.stackexchange.com.  I'm sure there has been proper research on this.

Comment: The Mac os defaulr browser already did it... can't remember de name